# jetty maven plugin doesn't deploy my second war

Tags: maven, jetty

I'm trying to deploy two wars on jetty, the first one is deployed, but the second one is not deployed. this is my configuration of the plugin:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${jetty.maven.plugin.version}</version>
<configuration>
    <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
    <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
    <war>${project.build.directory}/integration-test/webapp-fast.war</war>
    <webApp>
        <contextPath>/webapp-fast</contextPath>
    </webApp>
    <contextHandlers>  
        <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
          <war>${project.build.directory}/integration-test/stubs.war</war>
          <contextPath>/stubs</contextPath>
        </contextHandler>
            </contextHandlers>  
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>start-jetty</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>deploy-war</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
            <daemon>true</daemon>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>stop-jetty</id>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>stop</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: i'm using the following jetty plugin <jetty.maven.plugin.version>8.1.5.v20120716</jetty.maven.plugin.version>

Answer (score 0):

Try to deploy both wars using the contextHandlers:

```
<contextHandlers>  
    <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
      <war>${project.build.directory}/integration-test/stubs.war</war>
      <contextPath>/stubs</contextPath>
    </contextHandler>
    <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
      <war>${project.build.directory}/integration-test/webapp-fast.war</war>
      <contextPath>/webapp-fast</contextPath>
    </contextHandler>
</contextHandlers>
```

Comment: i'm trying to start up those two wars in a acceptance-tests maven project. When i try the configuration above, then it's trying to deploy my acceptance-tests maven project on jetty also.

Comment: i'm trying to start up those two wars in a acceptance-tests maven project. When i try the configuration above, then it's trying to deploy my acceptance-tests maven project on jetty also.This is the exception i'll get: `2012-12-20 15:41:44.634:WARN:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:Web application not found C:\Data\Development\Workspaces\FAST\acceptance-tests\target\acceptance-tests-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`

Comment: Try to run goal `start` instead of `deploy-war`